# Splash screen crash when change in android manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

My splash screen (**splash.java**) works fine , it appear for 5 sec when I call it **`Launcher`** in Android Manifest , but when i fix it as **`Default`** in Android Manifest and run it through **`List Activity`** (**Menu.java**) , it run for 5sec and then instead of going back to Menu.java it crashes with run time error . **I want it to appear for 5 sec and then go back to the menu.java.**

The manifest in which it not work for 5 sec but application crash run time after 5 sec (Unfortunately your application has stopped)

```
<activity
    android:name=".Menu"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.hello.SPLASH" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This splash.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
        tone = MediaPlayer.create(splash.this, R.raw.songg);
        tone.start();
        Thread haai = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally 
                {
                    Intent first = new Intent("com.example.hello.Menu");
                    startActivity(first);
                }
            }       
        };
        haai.start();
    }
```

Error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25707): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-30562
E/AndroidRuntime(25707): Process: com.example.hello, PID: 25707
E/AndroidRuntime(25707): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.hello.Menu }
E/AndroidRuntime(25707):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1672)
E/AndroidRuntime(25707):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1442)
E/AndroidRuntime(25707):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3511)
E/AndroidRuntime(25707):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3472)
E/AndroidRuntime(25707):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
E/AndroidRuntime(25707):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3714)
E/AndroidRuntime(25707):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3682)
E/AndroidRuntime(25707):    at com.example.hello.splash$1.run(splash.java:36)
```

I am not satisfied with my own answer because i am in learning stage so waiting for better answer with explanation of its working and problem.

Comment: Can you post the error log

Comment: I update my error log

Answer (score 3):

> ActivityNotFoundException: No

Because not Activity found with `com.example.hello.MENU` action in manifest.

To fix issue,use `com.example.hello.MENU` action string for `Menu` Activity. like:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Menu"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.hello.MENU" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Or you can start Activity using target Activity class name :

```
Intent intent=new Intent (splash.this,Menu.class);
splash.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I changed the intent filter as you guided and change `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` to `<action android:name="com.example.hello.MENU" />` but now its not even showing the apk , and second part is missing class after `new`

Comment: and why its not showing issue if i make .splash as Main Launcher

Comment: @ARG: remove `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` from Menu activity tag

Comment: then application is not even opening , which should be launcher then

Comment: @ARG: add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in `android:name=".splash"`

Comment: If i add this to .splash then it works this is what i mentioned in my question as well but i want menu as my main screen to appear first , i updated my logcat

Comment: It works , the second option , but it sometime make me to double click on the splash button and when i want to close it make me to 2/3 click back option for closing the application from menu , Can you please tell me why is it , so one can award the bounty for that and solve my question, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the manifest you have set the activity name .Menu whereas in the java code you have set it as MENU(uppercase).

```
<activity
    android:name=".Menu" <---- activity name as .Menu
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

In java code as:

```
Intent first = new Intent("com.example.hello.MENU")<---.MENU- its all uppercase
```

Change it in java code as below to fix your problem:

```
Intent first = new Intent("com.example.hello.Menu");
startActivity(first);
```

Comment: same error that unfortunately your app has stopped , when splash screen finish after 5 sec

Comment: Post the new error logs, before that just try chaging `<action android:name="com.example.hello.SPLASH" />` to `<action android:name="com.example.hello.splash" />`

Comment: error is in finding .menu , .splash work fine and application not break when i make .splash as MAIN LAUNCHER , I tried that above of changing SPLASH to splash but it doesnt work as well

Comment: You might have not corrected the activity name to `.Menu` either in java code or in the AndroidManifest.xml as I mentioned above

Comment: As i said it works if i make .splash as launcher as .Menu as Default

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer , its simple but I use the other way but still I don't find why the program works fine when `.splash` make as `Main` and `LAUNCHER` , but when make `.Menu` as `Main` and `LAUNCHER` program run but when I select splash from Menu List it run for 5 seconds then instead of going back to Menu again it crashes with runtime error . I changed the `.splash` code to the below code and it works but as I am new to android I don't know why the last way was not working.

```
public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally 
                {
                    try
                    {
                    Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.hello.Menu");
                    Intent myclass = new Intent(splash.this , ourclass);
                    startActivity(myclass);
                    }
                    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
```

I didn't change anything from Android Manifest

Comment: So, the code above works with `Menu` as `Launcher + Main` and `Splash` as `Default`?

Comment: yes but why its not working the other way and in this method sometime its just look like menu screen appear twice like you have to press back button twice , but why not the other method and whats the difference

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you declared intent action is .SPLASH but you create action is .MENU
change

```
Intent first = new Intent("com.example.hello.MENU");
                   startActivity(first);
```

to

```
Intent first = new Intent("com.example.hello.SPALSH");
                   startActivity(first);
```

or change your manifest like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hello.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I did but still crash problem

Comment: sorry, I was wrong with  android:name please see my edit

Comment: I dont want that when my application starts then splash screen appears , i want that menu appear first